# Loading json data to an array in d3

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, data-visualization

so I am trying to assign json data to an array variable in d3.

Here is my json:

```
[
{
    "Impressions": "273909",
    "Clicks": "648",
    "CPM": 4.6388278388278,
    "Cost": 1266.4,
    "CPC": 1.9543209876543,
    "Campaign": "Campaign 1"
},
{
    "Impressions": "974408",
    "Clicks": "14571",
    "CPM": 4.0175975359343,
    "Cost": 3913.14,
    "CPC": 0.26855672225654,
    "Campaign": "Campaign 2"
},
{
    "Impressions": "76751",
    "Clicks": "5022",
    "CPM": 8.4675,
    "Cost": 643.53,
    "CPC": 0.1281421744325,
    "Campaign": "Campaign 3"
},
```

and here is my code to load the json dataset:

```
d3.json("DS003a_Adwords_AdPerformance_modified.json", function(error, data) {



var topData = data.sort(function(a, b){
    return d3.descending(+a.cost, +b.cost);
}).slice(0,10);

topData.forEach(function (d) {
    d.CampaignName = d.Campaign;
    d.cost = d.Cost;
});

var cost = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) {return d.Cost;})
            .entries(data);  //fail


var p = d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
  .data(topData)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .text(function(d,i){
    return (i+1) + ". " + d.CampaignName + " cost = " + cost[i];
  });
```

I basically want to save the value of "Cost" to an array variable `var cost`. 
But when I tried my code the result is as followed:

[image]

What should i do?

Thank you, your help is appreciated :)

Comment: You should give us the code as text, not screen shots.

Comment: edited, thank you.

Comment: `cost[n]` is an object. Write a `console.log(cost[n])` and display all values of it. Then you have to access it like this: `cost[n].VALUE` or `cost[n]['VALUE']`.

Comment: Hi Phil, I tried, but now the result is undefined

Comment: Hi cyril, i tried and the result is still `undefined`. the json file is thousands of line long. I can give you the github link: https://github.com/beneditatan/d3_project/blob/master/campaign_performance/DS003a_Adwords_AdPerformance_modified.json 

i basically will need this `cost` variable for a chart, and the code will be:

`var chart = canvas.append('g')
      .attr("transform", "translate(150,0)")
      .attr('id','bars')
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(cost) //fail
      .enter()
      .append('rect')`

Comment: What i am trying to tell is that I don't find a good reason why you are using nest as the campaign is unique and cost is also unique. Is it for some purpose? In case you don't nest then its a simple ball game here is the working fiddle. http://plnkr.co/edit/492ZwYhFPnLRxn0sniNl?p=preview

Comment: no, i just need to store the values of cost in an array variable and i dont know how to do this. I thought nest is one of the method. I'm just looking for a method to achieve this.

Comment: oh wah thank you. But by using d3.nest() does it make `var cost` an array variable?

Comment: Nopes it doesn't d3.nest is used for grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `nest` to directly have an array of values. The two possible output formats of nest are:

- a large object

  ```
  { 
   key1: value1, 
   key2: value2,
   ...
  }
  ```
- or an array of small objects

  ```
  [ 
   { key: key1, values: value1 },
   { key: key2, values: value2 }, 
   ...
  ]
  ```

Neither is the one you desire. (Remember the first goal of nest: identify a  set of keys, and group all pieces of data with the same key in a single batch, possibly with some transformation).

If for some reason you don't want to use your original array as suggested in the comments, then `d3.map` is what you're needing:

```
var cost = d3.map(data, function(d) {
   return d.cost;
});
```

This is creating a copy of your cost data (if your data array changes, then you will need to run `d3.map` again to update your array). So you should use this array only locally if your data may not be constant. This is why in general one prefers using the original data directly, as it also saves this copy step and has less risks of tricky bugs later on.